# Getting error in Admob native template "Unexpected resource type"

Tags: admob, native-ads

```
<com.google.android.ads.nativetemplates.TemplateView
   android:id="@+id/my_template"
   app:gnt_template_type="@layout/gnt_small_template_view"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXx55.jpg)

After adding this code in xml, getting error for the line "@layout/gnt_small_template_view" error "Unexpected resource type:'layout' expected:string"

Help to solve the issue.